# Sour and acid taste

Tags: synonyms

Is there a difference between *sour* and *acid*, or these can be used interchangeably?

Comment: [The five elements of taste perception: **salty, sour, bitter, sweet** and **umami**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste_bud). I'd assume **acid** is approximately a "synonym" for **sour** in the context of *tastes*. But figuratively, a **sour** remark is actually **bitter**, whereas an **acid** comment could well be an example of rubbing **salt** in your victim's wounds (it *stings/burns*).

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers!
So, acid is more *caustic* in all contexts, right?

Comment: http://www.diffen.com/difference/Bitter_vs_Sour: "Sourness, on the other hand, is indicative of acidity."

Comment: With a little search it can be understood easily.

Comment: It should be noted that some people seem to use _both_ "sour" and "bitter" to describe the same taste, whether that taste is due to acid or base.  This drives me crazy, but maybe there's a genuine physiological variation involved.

Answer (score 1):

Acidity, a chemical property, accounts for a sour taste.